# Laravel 5.4 Response File -> Error in File

Tags: php, file, laravel-5, response

I am working with Laravel 5.4 and save some JPEG-Files to Storage with

```
`Storage::disk('local')->put('upload/pictures/full-size/'.$filename ,$picture);`
```

And now i try to get this pictures again which i tryed like

...

Routes:

```
Route::get('pictures/full/{filename}', ['as' => 'picture_full', 'uses' => 'ImageController@getFull']);
```

...

Image Controller:

```
public function getFull(Image $image)
{
    $path = storage_path('app/'.Config::get('pictures.icon_size').$image->filename);
    $handler = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File($path);

    $header_content_type = $handler->getMimeType();
    $header_content_length = $handler->getSize();

    $headers = array(
        'Content-Type' => $header_content_type,
        'Content-Length' => $header_content_length
    );

    return response()->file($path, $headers);
}
```

So now my Problem is, that the file can't be shown.
The Browser says the File contains an Error.

Tryed a lot, but just don't see what I am making wrong.
Anyone has an idea?

Comment: The Browser console shows me the warning - _Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type image/jpeg: "URL"._

Comment: My solution was now: _ob_end_clean();_

Comment: ob_end_clean() saved my life.